# Simple nested query on the same table

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

So this is my table set up of 100k rows. I have around 30k rows which have the wrong dealer associated to it even though it refers to the same person but just a different bank designation. This happened due to a failure to port information accurately from a previous version of the database .

```
Table CustomerName

 Name Bank Dealer SSN
 John  1    ABC    unique1
 Mike  1    DEF    unique2
 Mike  2    wrong  unique2
 Mark  1    XYZ    unique3
 Mark  2    wrong  unique3
```

Desired Table set up

```
Table CustomerName

 Name Bank Dealer  SSN
 John  1    ABC    unique1
 Mike  1    DEF    unique2
 Mike  2    DEF    unique2
 Mark  1    XYZ    unique3
 Mark  2    XYZ    unique3
```

I want to write a query which will target the rows (Bank 2 rows essentially) and change it to Bank 1 Dealer values. Is there a way to do it ? I'm using T-SQL ( SSMS 2016 )

EDIT : 
SSN are like primary keys for the customer. every customer will have one ssn . the bank 2 is basically a delinquent account bank. A customer may or may not have a bank 2 account , but they'll have a bank 1 account. But my problem is that somehow the dealer didn't come through right for bank 2 and I need to update to the correct value

Comment: Can the SSNs be relied on? Can one SSN "belong to" multiple dealers? Will there always be a bank 1 entry if a bank 2 entry is present?

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ yea, SSN are like primary keys for the customer. every customer will have one ssn . the bank 2 is basically a delinquent account bank. A customer may or may not have a bank 2 account , but they'll have a bank 1 account. But my problem is that somehow the dealer didn't come through right for bank 2 and I need to update to the correct value

Comment: I think Gordon's answer will do exactly what you want; I couldn't have written it any better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is which `Dealer` to use.  Let me guess that it is the first one.  You can use CTE and `update` to accomplish this:

```
with topudate as (
      select cn.*,
             max(case when bank = 1 then dealer end) over (partition by ssn) as dealer1
      from customername cn
     )
update toupdate
    set dealer = dealer1
    where dealer <> dealer1 or dealer is null;
```

If you have some other logic for getting the right name, then that would go in the `case` expression instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
update bank2 
   set bank2.dealer = bank1.dealer 
  from CustomerName bank1 
  join CustomerName bank2 
        on bank2.SSN = bank1.SSN 
       and bank2.Bank = 2  
       and bank1.Bank = 1
```